# Proper use of Stored Procedure using Select

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I created a Stored Procedure where I can select the column that I address in my Stored Procedure via Callable Statement. I tried to use **`SELECT SECTION NAME FROM allsections_list WHERE SECTION_NAME = ?`** Similar to syntax of Prepared Statement but I think its not compatible using this syntax. I'm just new learning this mysql.

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE getSECTION_NAME(OUT SECTION_NAME VARCHAR)
SELECT SECTION_NAME FROM allsections_list
```

**Code**

```
 private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String searchSection = Section_SearchSection_Textfield.getText();
    String searchSection_Name = Section_SectionName_TextField.getText();

    if (searchSection.isEmpty())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill up this fields");
    }
    else 

        try (Connection myConn = DBUtil.connect();
             CallableStatement myCs = myConn.prepareCall("{call getSECTION_NAME(?)}"))
        {
            myCs.setString(1, searchSection_Name);

            try (ResultSet myRs = myCs.executeQuery())
            {
                int resultsCounter = 0;
                while (myRs.next())
                {
                    String getSection_Name = myRs.getString(1);
                    Section_SectionName_TextField.setText(getSection_Name);
                    resultsCounter++;
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            DBUtil.processException(e);
        }
```

When I search a records. If the records exist it the value will print out to the textfields. But it doesn't print out. And it throws me a error **`getSECTION_NAME does not exist`**. What if I want select multiple values? Because I'm having a project where I'm making a Enrollment System. I choose this Stored Procedure specially than Batch Statement based on what I read. Any help will appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: try not to use stored procedures, they introduce a dependency on your db. Your db is just for storing the data.

Comment: @NimChimpsky What if I want to select multiple values?

Comment: dynamic queries are almost never a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

I don't use MySql, but here's a similar example in Oracle (I think this Works in MySql  as well).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_section_name(OUT secName VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
SELECT SECTION_NAME INTO secName FROM allsections_list WHERE some_condition   = 100; //your procedure does not use any input arguments if you want to return just one record then you'll probably need to specify a where clause
END
/  //when executing a stored procedure in a DB  client you will need to specify a terminator character (in this case slash /)
```

Note that there's no return statement because we're using OUT parameters.

The getOutValueForStoredProcedure method calls the stored procedure and retrieves the out value.

```
public String getOutValueForStoredProcedure(String procedureName, int sqlType) throws EasyORMException{

    String out=null;
    CallableStatement stmt=null;
    try{
            //out parameters must me marked with question marks just as input parameters
          sqlQuery = "{call " + procedureName +"(?)}";
          stmt=conn.prepareCall(sqlQuery);//I assume that a Connection has been created

          stmt.registerOutParameter(1, sqlType);

          stmt.execute();    

          out = stmt.getString(1);//you get the out variable through the Statement, not the ResultSet

    }catch(Exception e){
          //log exception
    }finally{
          //close stmt
    }
    return out;
}
```

To call this stored procedure, you can use

```
   String out = getOutValueForStoredProcedure("get_section_name", java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
```

For creating stored procedures in MySql , check this link http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures-in-mysql-5--net-17843

For a more elaborate example, check this http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-out-parameter-example/

Comment: @Downvoter, care to explain the reason for downvote so that I can improve my answer?